# Как можно выключить touch mode для listview?

Tags: android, listview

Передвижение по listView должно происходить с помощью навигационных клавиш то есть touch
screen'а в устройстве нет. Нужно, чтобы первый пункт автоматически выделялся после запуска приложения, пишу `listView.setSelection(0);`, но при запуске включается touch mode. Проверяла, `listview.isInTouchMode()` возвращает `true`. Дальше, если нажимать клавиши, все работает как надо.

Можно, конечно, разрешить фокус в touch mode, и вызывать то же, что происходит при выборе первого пункта. Но это костыли.
Как можно выключить touch mode в listview? Или, альтернативно, можно ли вызвать onItemSelected соответствующего listener'а? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

Или же попробуйте отнаследоваться от ListView и переопределить onTouchEvent.

Ещё, как вариант, вызывайте requestFocusFromTouch() перед setSelection.

Comment: Пробую, не работает. Даже не подсвечивает пункт, не то чтобы обработчик вызывать. 
Может быть, эмулировать нажатие клавиши? Но как?

Comment: Все три варианта не работают?

Comment: Второй не знаю как может помочь, onTouchEvent ведь обрабатывает входящие сигналы касания, которых просто нет и быть не может.
Первый не работает, третий сейчас попробую.

Comment: requestFocusFromTouch() работает. Спасибо))